# ORA-31061: XDB error: special char to escaped char conversion failed

Tags: oracle, oracle-xml-db, oracle-xml-publisher, oracle-xml-db-repository, xml-error

I'm completely new to Oracle's XDB, trying to breakfix a code in production environment which i am completely new to.

```
SELECT  DBMS_LOB.SubStr(RTRIM (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (E,XMLATTRIBUTES (ntx.nttx_str || '|' AS "Seg")) ORDER BY ntx.ref_id, ntx.ntnb_input_dtm desc)
                                   .EXTRACT ('./E[not(@Seg = preceding-sibling::E/@Seg)]/@Seg').GetClobVal(),','),1000,1)
    FROM
       (SELECT umum.ref_id,
               ntnb.ntnb_input_dtm,
               DBMS_LOB.SubStr(RTRIM (XMLAGG (XMLELEMENT (E,XMLATTRIBUTES (nttx.nttx_text || '' AS "Seg")) ORDER BY nttx.nttx_seq_no asc)
                                   .EXTRACT ('./E[not(@Seg = preceding-sibling::E/@Seg)]/@Seg').GetClobVal(),','),500,1) AS nttx_str
        FROM umum_util_mgt umum,
             ntnb_note_base ntnb,
             nttx_note_text nttx
        WHERE ntnb.ntnb_id = umum.ntnb_id
          AND ntnb.ntnb_id = nttx.ntnb_id
          AND ntnb.ntnb_input_dtm = nttx.ntnb_input_dtm
          GROUP BY umum.ref_id, ntnb.ntnb_input_dtm
        ) ntx,
        php_mdx_auth_ext_tbl paex
        WHERE ntx.ref_id = paex.ref_id*
```

When i try to execute the above query, Oracle is returning the below error

**ORA-31061: XDB error: special char to escaped char conversion failed.**

This used to work in older version of Oracle, after moving to oracle 12c we are facing this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error generally occurs when there is a control character (Bad data) present in the XML data.

I am able to reproduce the error with bad XML data but yes, error code is different, I am not sure why.

> ```
> SQL> WITH DATAA AS (
>   2      SELECT UNISTR('SO\0013bad') TEST FROM DUAL
>   3      UNION ALL
>   4      SELECT UNISTR('SO\00aegood') TEST FROM DUAL
>   5  )
>   6  SELECT xmlelement("a", test) AS TEST
>   7    FROM DATAA;
> ERROR:
> ORA-64451: Conversion of special character to escaped character failed.
> ```

To resolve this error,

1. You need to find out the records with bad XML data and correct those data. You can use `REGEXP_LIKE` as following to find the bad XML data and correct those data:

> ```
> SQL> WITH DATAA AS (
>   2      SELECT UNISTR('SO\0013bad') TEST FROM DUAL
>   3      UNION ALL
>   4      SELECT UNISTR('SO\00aegood') TEST FROM DUAL
>   5  )
>   6  SELECT *
>   7  FROM DATAA
>   8  WHERE REGEXP_LIKE ( TEST, '[[:cntrl:]]' );
>
> TEST
> -------
> SObad
>
> SQL>
> ```

**-- OR --**

2. You can use `REGEXP_REPLACE` to skip the control characters preent in the XML data from processing as follows:

> ```
> SQL> WITH DATAA AS (
>   2      SELECT UNISTR('SO\0013bad') TEST FROM DUAL
>   3      UNION ALL
>   4      SELECT UNISTR('SO\00aegood') TEST FROM DUAL
>   5  )
>   6  SELECT xmlelement("a", REGEXP_REPLACE(TEST, '[[:cntrl:]]', '')) AS TEST
>   7    FROM DATAA;
>
> TEST
> --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
> <a>SObad</a>
> <a>SO«good</a>
>
> SQL>
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks Mate! It worked just perfect. I used REGEXP_REPLACE to skip the control characters.

Comment: Welcome @Tedgeor. Happy to hear that it helped!! Keep coding and Keep learning... Cheers!!